# mount - can't find /dev/sdc in fstab error

Tags: centos, redhat, mount, fstab

I'm trying to mount xfs disk.

I prepared directories.

```
sudo mkdir /grid/;
sudo mkdir /grid/0;
```

then I tried

```
sudo mount -t xfs /dev/sdc /grid/0;
```

But I always receive

> can't find /dev/sdc /grid/0 in /etc/fstab

My fstab looks like this

```
#
# /etc/fstab
# Created by anaconda on Tue Dec 18 11:05:19 2018
#
# Accessible filesystems, by reference, are maintained under '/dev/disk'
# See man pages fstab(5), findfs(8), mount(8) and/or blkid(8) for more info
#
/dev/mapper/rhel-root   /                       xfs     defaults        0 0
UUID=xxx                /boot                   xfs     defaults        0 0
UUID=zzz                /boot/efi               vfat    umask=0077,shortname=winnt 0 0
/dev/mapper/rhel-home   /home                   xfs     defaults        0 0
/dev/mapper/rhel-var_log /var/log                xfs     defaults        0 0
/dev/mapper/rhel-swap   swap                    swap    defaults        0 0
/dev/sdc        /grid/0         xfs     defaults,noatime    0 0
/dev/sdd        /grid/1         xfs     defaults,noatime    0 0
/dev/sde        /grid/2         xfs     defaults,noatime    0 0
/dev/sdf        /grid/3         xfs     defaults,noatime    0 0
/dev/sdg        /grid/4         xfs     defaults,noatime    0 0
/dev/sdh        /grid/5         xfs     defaults,noatime    0 0
/dev/sdi        /grid/6         xfs     defaults,noatime    0 0
/dev/sdj        /grid/7         xfs     defaults,noatime    0 0
```

is something wrong with my fstab ? I can't find what I did wrong.

edit: lsblk

```
NAME             MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda                8:0    0 447.1G  0 disk 
\u251c\u2500sda1             8:1    0   200M  0 part /boot/efi
\u251c\u2500sda2             8:2    0     1G  0 part /boot
\u2514\u2500sda3             8:3    0 445.9G  0 part 
  \u251c\u2500rhel-root    253:0    0 361.9G  0 lvm  /
  \u251c\u2500rhel-swap    253:1    0     4G  0 lvm  [SWAP]
  \u251c\u2500rhel-home    253:2    0    50G  0 lvm  /home
  \u2514\u2500rhel-var_log 253:3    0    30G  0 lvm  /var/log
sdc                8:32   0   3.7T  0 disk 
sdd                8:48   0   3.7T  0 disk 
sde                8:64   0   3.7T  0 disk 
sdf                8:80   0   3.7T  0 disk 
sdg                8:96   0   3.7T  0 disk 
sdh                8:112  0   3.7T  0 disk 
sdi                8:128  0   3.7T  0 disk 
sdj                8:144  0   3.7T  0 disk
```

Comment: Hello. May you please provide output of **lsblk** ?

Comment: I've just added lsblk output into original post. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Hm, try also `parted /dev/sdc` and then `print` in parted prompt.


Also, run `mount -a` in order to check, if **/etc/fstab** is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was caused by non-breakable space which was mixed in fstab records and in mount command.

After converting text to ASCII and checking on "Show All Characters" in notepad++ I replaced all non-breakable space with ordinary space and command finished successfully.